# Is possible to add bootstrap tooltip on dd tag ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I tried different ways  but none of them works.

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  ...
  <dt>tooltip</dt>
  <dd id='status' title="my tooltip"><%= @order.status %></dd>    
</dd>
```

my coffeescript

```
$ ->
 $('#status').tooltip
  placement: 'right'
  trigger: 'hover focus'
```

Comment: You can add a div to embrace the entire contents of the dd and put the title in there...

Comment: @RubyRacer `<div id="status" title="my tooltip!"> <dd>...</dd> </div>`  doesn't work.

Comment: No, it should be <dd><div...></div></dd>

Comment: @RubyRacer nothing: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rk31a23x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rk31a23x/) was using jQuery 1.6.4. Bootstrap v3.2.0 supports jQuery 1.9.0 and above [according to their `bower.json`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/bower.json#L36). After changing jQuery to 1.9.1 in the fiddle, it works as expected given your original code.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rk31a23x/3/